# Телеграм бот отправляет старые данные из Googlt таблиц

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet, python-telegram-bot, google-sheets-api

Сделал телеграм бота на Python, который на определенный запрос отправляет данные из гугл таблиц.
Но при обновлении данных в таблице, бот продолжает отправлять старые.
Как сделать так, чтобы получать свежие данные, как только записал их в таблице? Или хотя бы с небольшой задержкой.
Я не программист, бота делал по примерам, так что на кривость не ругайтесь. Главное он работает и выдает то, что мне нужно. Но не обновляет новые данные.

```
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from config import token
import keyboards as kb
from config import spreadsheetId
import gspread
import httplib2
import apiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# --- Google Sheets ---
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'
spreadsheet_id = spreadsheetId

# Авторизуемся и получаем service — экземпляр доступа к API
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    CREDENTIALS_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth)

gc = gspread.service_account(filename="credentials.json")
sheet = gc.open("ABC").sheet1
data = sheet.get_all_records()
sh = gc.open("ABC")

# --- Получаем данные из гугл таблиц ---
mon = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B3:B8'), []))
tue = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B10:B15'), []))

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Понедельник':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Данные на понедельник:\n' + mon)
    elif message.text == 'Вторник':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Данные на вторник:\n' + tue)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что вы из гугл таблиц данные запрашиваете лишь один раз - при запуске бота, насколько я понял, следующие строчки:

```
sheet = gc.open("ABC").sheet1
data = sheet.get_all_records()
sh = gc.open("ABC")

# --- Получаем данные из гугл таблиц ---
mon = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B3:B8'), []))
tue = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B10:B15'), []))
```

Чтобы данные вытаскивались при обращении к боту пользователем нужно их поместить в функцию обработки запроса:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    sheet = gc.open("ABC").sheet1
    data = sheet.get_all_records()
    sh = gc.open("ABC")
    
    # --- Получаем данные из гугл таблиц ---
    mon = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B3:B8'), []))
    tue = '\n'.join(sum(sh.sheet1.get('B10:B15'), []))
    
    if message.text == 'Понедельник':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Данные на понедельник:\n' + mon)
    elif message.text == 'Вторник':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Данные на вторник:\n' + tue)
```

Могу быть не точным в том, что может быть и авторизацию в гугл сервисах нужно туда же поместить, но суть Вы поняли.